# checks inside action creators

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am creating simple app, which makes GET requests to the server, then prepares recieved data and creates chart. There are few questions:

1. Where should I place code responsible for checking and preparing raw data. Currently I have it in my action creators, but maybe it needs to be in the component itself?
2. I need to check and compare prepared data with the data which is already used for the chart, and do not call re-render if it's the same or not valid. Where should I put this check? For now I think to place it inside action creators too. But for that I need to use `getState()` for accessing the state, doesn't look right.
3. Action creators seems right place for all these checks for me, because if data is not valid, I can simply not update my state with it, (e.g. do not dispatch certain action creator) Or maybe I have to update state with new data despite it is not valid?

given these action creators, what is the best place for described checks?:

```
     export function fetchPopulations(term = "") {
          return function (dispatch) {
               dispatch(fetchingPopulations())

               term=toTitleCase(term)

               return fetch(`${API_URL}${term.replace(/\s/g, '%20')}`)
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(json => dispatch(requestPopulations(json)))
      }
  }

  export function requestPopulations(data = []) {
      return {
          type: REQUEST_POPULATIONS,
          payload: data,
      }
  }
  export function fetchingPopulations() {
      return {
          type: FETCHING_POPULATIONS
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are doing it right.

In your example, `requestPopulations` and `fetchingPopulations` are the real action creators and `fetchPopulations` is a composing function (yes, composing functions for the win!).

1. > Where should I place code responsible for checking and preparing raw
   >       data. Currently I have it in my action creators, but maybe it needs
   >       to be in the component itself?

   Components are not the place for putting the business logic of our application. Components should only represent the **View** in our MVC. No API calls, no business logic, only props and state.
2. > I need to check and compare prepared data with the data which is
   >   already used for the chart, and do not call re-render if it's the same
   >   or not valid. Where should I put this check? For now I think to place
   >   it inside action creators too. But for that I need to use getState()
   >   for accessing the state, doesn't look right.

   Create modular functions (it really shines with code maintenance and reuse) for performing these checks, compose them together in another one along with your real action creators, and you can dispatch only if needed. Further optimization can be done inside component life cycle hook `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`. Also I think it is definitely not an anti-pattern to use methods with a signature like this:

   ```
   export function myComposingFunction(params) {
       return (dispatch, getState) => {
           // ...
   ```

   So you can use `getState()`.
3. > Action creators seems right place for all these checks for me, because
   >   if data is not valid, I can simply not update my state with it, (e.g.
   >   do not dispatch certain action creator) Or maybe I have to update
   >   state with new data despite it is not valid?

   No, do not update the state with useless data. If you do that you will re-render the entire tree for nothing. You were absolutely right to say "if data is not valid, I can simply not update my state with it, (e.g. do not dispatch certain action creator)"